# Problema al subir imagen - Django rest framework

Tags: javascript, django, vue.js, django-models, djangorestframework

Tengo 2 modelos **User y EcoUser** con relación de 1 a 1 (he reducido los fields de las tablas para este ejemplo):

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    picture_url = models.ImageField(upload_to='logos/', blank=True)

class EcoUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='eco_user')
    document = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

En el cual utilizo un NestedSerializer para poder crear y actualizar los datos de las dos tablas en un solo **post** o **put** de esta manera hice el actualizar ya que en el registrar no guardo imagenes y no tengo problema con ello:

Este es el **serializer**

```
class EcoUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

 user = UserSerializer(required=True)

 class Meta:
     model = EcoUser
     fields = '__all__'

 def update(self, instance, validated_data):
     instance.document = validated_data.get('document', instance.document)
     instance.save()
     user_data = validated_data.pop('user')
     user = instance.user
     user.picture_url = user_data.get('picture_url', user.picture_url)
     user.save()
     return instance
```

y en mi **viewset**

```
class EcoUserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = EcoUserSerializer
    queryset = EcoUser.objects.all()
    pagination_class = None
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser,)

    @transaction.atomic
    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        with transaction.atomic():
            try:
                instance = self.get_object()
                instance.id = kwargs.get('pk')
                serializer = EcoUserSerializer(instance=instance, data=request.data)
                print(serializer)
                if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                    self.perform_update(serializer)
                    return Response({"status": True, "results": "Datos actualizados correctamente"},
                                    status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            except ValidationError as err:
                return Response({"status": False, "error_description": err.detail}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Esto funcionaba correctamente hasta cuando agregue el campo **ImageField** ya no me actualiza los datos y me bota un error 400 bad request.
Esto le mando del **VUEJS** por **axios**:

```
const bodyFormData = new FormData();
bodyFormData.append('user.picture_url', this.params.user.picture_url.name);
bodyFormData.append('document', this.params.document);
this.axios.put(`/users/${this.params.id}/`, bodyFormData, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' } })
  .then((response) => {
    this.isSending = false;
    this.$snackbar.open(response.data.results);
  });
```

Esta bien si en el apppend como nombre de campo le pongo **user.picture_url**? ya que esta dentro del objeto user y luego ya accedo al **picture_url** para poder actualizarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probe del postman y me di cuenta del error:
Simplemente era que el campo username de la tabla user del django era obligatorio:

```
const bodyFormData = new FormData();
bodyFormData.append('user.picture_url', this.params.user.picture_url.name);
bodyFormData.append('document', this.params.document);
bodyFormData.append('user.username', this.params.username);
```

y funciono de maravilla. :D